# Composite Control Textbox and AutoCompleteExtender

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm trying to make composite web control contains  TextBox and AutoCompleteExtender  i followed this article http://byatool.com/?p=244 when i run the page i got nothing just empty page and i got this

```
<div>
    <span id="AutoCompleteTextBox2" FirstRowSelected="false" OnClientPopulated="ClientPopulated" CompletionListHighlightedItemCssClass="autocomplete_highlightedListItem"></span>
</div>
```

rather than textbox

Answer (score 2):

i did not fins solution but i changed my way to solve the problem and rebuild the control based on Script Control like this [article](http://byatool.com/?p=329)